# find value in group in python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

i have data that looks like this:

```
is severe      sn_id
1                1
0                1
1                2
1                2
```

what I want to do is to create a column in the data that will say YES or No according to the following "rule":
for each group of snp_id if i have at least one "1" and at lest one "zero" in the is_sever column
it will return yes else NO ( the is_sever and snp_id have str type of data
example:

```
is severe      sn_id     yes\no
    1                1      yes
    0                1       yes
    1                2       no
    1                2       no
```

no

what i tried to do is this:

```
df['Value2']=np.where(df.groupby(df["snp_id"])['is_severe'].transform(lambda x: ((x=='1' ) & (x=="0")).any()), 'YES','NO')
```

but all the values were "no" is there any way to fix this ? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare `set`s:

```
m = df.groupby("snp_id")['is severe'].transform(lambda x: set(x) >= set([0,1]))
#if values are strings
m = df.groupby("snp_id")['is severe'].transform(lambda x: set(x) >= set(['0','1']))
df['Value2']=np.where(m, 'YES','NO')
```

If only `0, 1` values in `is_severe` you can compare number of unique values by [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
m = df.groupby("snp_id")['is severe'].transform('nunique').eq(2)
df['Value2']=np.where(m, 'YES','NO')
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
m = df.groupby("snp_id")['is severe'].transform(lambda x:((x==1).any() and (x==0).any()))
#if values are strings
m=df.groupby("snp_id")['is severe'].transform(lambda x:((x=='1').any() and (x=='0').any()))
df['Value2']=np.where(m, 'YES','NO')
```

Comment: hi , it still gives only "no"  the is_severe column is str type maybe the set doest work on it?

Comment: after the edit it still goves only "no"